# Python creating new dataframe grouping and summarizing column

Tags: python, sql, calculated-columns

I have the below SQL query that creates a new table that summarizes each visit counts by User ID. How do I create this dataframe in python?

```
create table User_Visits_summary as
select user_id,
sum(case when visit_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Type_One_Counts,
sum(case when visit_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Type_Two_Counts,
sum(case when visit_type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Type_Three_Counts,
count(*) as Total_Visits
from user_visits
group by user_id
```

Comment: Where/how is your data stored?  Is `user_visits` already a dataframe/numpy array/list in Python?  Or is it stored in a SQL database which you have already connected to Python?  The lastest version of Pandas has some capability for direct handling of SQL statements (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html).  However it is more efficient(faster) to translate your SQL statement to Pandas indexing/aggregation statements.

Comment: Yes, user_visits is already a dataframe in Python. I want to create a new dataframe named User_Visits_summary that captures what the SQL does above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should create the same table as the SQL query.  Read the comments in the code, and execute in debug mode to understand better what each line of code does.  For a useful guide on Pandas functions, check out this cheatsheet-

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

```
import pandas as pd

# example dataset
user_visits = pd.DataFrame({'user_id'   :['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                            'visit_type':[  1,  1,  3,  3,  3,  2,  2,  2,  2] })

# This summary table already contains the data you want, but on 'long column' format
User_Visits_summary = user_visits.groupby(['user_id','visit_type']).size().reset_index()

# Here we pivot the table to get to your desired format
User_Visits_summary = User_Visits_summary.pivot(index='user_id',columns='visit_type', values=0)

# Calculate total from sub-totals in new column
User_Visits_summary['Total_Visits'] = User_Visits_summary.sum(axis=1)    

# Some formatting
User_Visits_summary.reset_index(inplace=True)
User_Visits_summary.rename(columns={1:'Type_One_Counts',
                                    2:'Type_Two_Counts',
                                    3:'Type_Three_Counts'}, inplace=True)

# Table ready
print(User_Visits_summary)
# ...too wide to paste...
```